# Global sections of $\mathcal{O}(k)$ over $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

I have the following example from Well's book on differential analysis on complex manifolds.
[image]
I don't currently understand why they get the description for $\mathcal{O}(\Bbb P_1(\Bbb C), E^k)$ from the resulting power series.

For example with $k = 1$, this becomes $$w\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nw^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nw^{n+1}$$ and this should reflect that there are no global sections in some sense?

Comment: For $k=1$ we get $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n(1/w)^n=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty b_nw^{n+1}$, and this is possible only if all $a_n$ and all $b_n$ vanish, because the functions $w^n$ for $n\in\mathbb Z$ are linearly independent. For other $k$ the argument is analogous.

Comment: @danneks what do you mean by the functions being linearly independent? I don’t think we have made that kind of an assumption.

Comment: They are linearly independent as functions on the punctured complex plane, because the Laurent series is unique for example.